# How to turn on cpu and network debugging messages/syslogd to read via klogd/syslogd in linux?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, syslog

For example:
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump

turns on I/O debugging messages which I can then parse for process wise I/O operations. I want to do the same for CPU operations and network operations per process.

I know there are command line tools like top,ps, netstat etc and a lot of information available in /proc/ directory too. But this is for a research project and it is important for me to get kernel level timestamps.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Systemtap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) for your requirement.

Following text is from their site:

> SystemTap provides free software (GPL)
>   infrastructure to simplify the
>   gathering of information about the
>   running Linux system. This assists
>   diagnosis of a performance or
>   functional problem. SystemTap
>   eliminates the need for the developer
>   to go through the tedious and
>   disruptive instrument, recompile,
>   install, and reboot sequence that may
>   be otherwise required to collect data.
>
> SystemTap provides a simple command
>   line interface and scripting language
>   for writing instrumentation for a live
>   running kernel. We are publishing
>   samples, as well as enlarging the
>   internal "tapset" script library to
>   aid reuse and abstraction.
>
> Among other tracing/probing tools,
>   SystemTap is the tool of choice for
>   complex tasks that may require live
>   analysis, programmable on-line
>   response, and whole-system symbolic
>   access. SystemTap can also handle
>   simple tracing jobs.

Comment: Thanks a lot..That's the kind of probing I needed.

Comment: @Kurchi, if you are satisfied with the answer, may be you can think of accepting the answer! ;)